# Is Body Centred Cubic arrangement also a kind of packing in solids?

Tags: physical-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry

I am confused about the packing thing in solids . I read about Hexagonal Closed packing(HCP) and Cubic closed packing(CCP) then realised this stuff named as Body Centred Cubic(BCC) under the heading of "Arrangement in solids" . Now what is the real difference between packing and arrangement? After all they are arranged in 3d and finally form a crystal

IT would be very kind if someone can clear my doubt... :)

Comment: The real difference between packing and arrangement is that some authors prefer the former term and some the latter.

Comment: Perhaps better put, body centered cubic is a Bravais lattice, and many pure metals exist as bcc crystals.